# How to pass persistent data to addEventListener in javascript?

Tags: javascript

In javascript I can do this:

```
var mydata = {foo:"bar"};
element.addEventListener("click", myFunc);

function myFunc(e) {
    // need to get {foo:"bar"}
}
```

I want to access the `mydata` variable from the myFunc function, but passed as parameter data, whenever the click event happens in the element. I don't want to get it through some global variable. I want to get that data passed in somehow. Something like this, if it existed:

```
var mydata = {foo:"bar"};
element.addEventListener("click", mydata, myFunc);

function myFunc(e) {
    var mydata = e.data;
}
```

Does anyone know a way? And no, you can't use jquery or any plugins.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass it directly. But below idea should work

```
element.addEventListener('click', myFunc);
element.mData = mydata;
function myFunc(e)
{
  console.log( e.target.mData );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an anonymous function on the event listener method. And also add the data as an element property.

```
element.mydata = {foo:"bar"};
element.addEventListener("click", function(){ myFunc(this.mydata); });
```

Hence

```
function myFunc(e){
  console.log(e.foo); //outputs "bar";
}
```